# Using SharedLocalizer and javascript in ASP.Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using asp.net core 2.0 to develop my MVC application. However, I am using the SharedLocalizer in the view. I use the following code to inject it:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> SharedLocalizer
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> SharedHtmlLocalizer
```

This is how I call my SharedLocalizer:

```
function updateCommission(agentID) {
    var msg = '@SharedLocalizer["Confirm Update Commission?"].Value.ToString()';
    if (confirm(msg) == false)
        return false;
}
```

But, my result looks like this:
[image]

If I use the SharedLocalizer in my html label / input, it displays fine. When I view my page source, the string also is the '$#1231';

How can I display the correct string with my setup?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Returns markup that is not HTML encoded   `@Html.Raw`

**refactor**

```
function updateCommission(agentID) {
    var msg = '@Html.Raw(SharedLocalizer["Confirm Update commission?"].Value.ToString())';
        return confirm(msg);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Working with ASP.NET Core 3.1.6 and JS ES6